# Why are my rotational controls also applying to another craft in the vicinity of mine?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I appear to have a bug where when I rotate a completely separate craft near to a spacestation or probe etc, the spacestation, probe etc also rotates (in this case near is about 100m).

If I turn off all reaction wheels and rcs the rotation does not occur, therefore I think that it is a bug that causes my rotational controls to also apply to any craft in my vicinity.

For reference and probably the cause of it is Dark Multiplayer but I just wanted to as to just check that it wasn't me being a moron :P

Comment: Do you have any other mods installed?

Comment: @SaintWacko no thats the only one (unless you count the Squad one :P)

Comment: Is this an actual question or just a bug report?

Comment: @Philipp its a question if it was something that I was screwing up or if it was an actual bug

Comment: Safe to say that “rotating completely different craft” is a bug, not a user error. You should probably cut-and-paste this into a bug report to [KSP Support](https://kerbalspaceprogram.com/en/?page_id=23).